# Store Key Value Pair in Azure and change the value in a Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, rest, azure-function-async

I need to store a simple Key Value Pair in Microsoft Azure, but I want to be able to change the Key with a Azure Function. Where can I store it and how can I change it programmatically?

The Key Value Pair is for the authentication for an rest api. Most of the calls need an access-token, which is retrieved via a login. The Problem is I want to run my function automatically with a timetrigger.

When I retrieve a token I also get a refresh-token, with the refresh-token and another rest-call it is possible to get a new access-token AND a new refresh-token.
So if I can save the refresh-token and would be able to update it programmatically inside Azure, it would be possible to let my function run automatically.

I already tried the appsettings and the keyvault, but I was only able to read their values and not to change them.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the appsettings using PowerShell `Set-AzureRmWebApp` or `Set-AzureRmWebAppSlot` commands with `-AppSettings` parameter.

```
Set-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AppServiceNameCm -Slot $SlotStage -AppSettings $appSettingHash
```

Details about how you write Azure Functions using PowerShell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell)

Comment: I want to change the value automatically with a function. It would be best if the function, which reads it and uses it, would be able to change it directly without any input.
Can the function use Powershell commands?